# Alignment of Eigen matrices in an `std::array`

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an application where I need to pass N `Eigen` matrices to some functions. N is a compile-time constant, and these functions are called a significant number of times within tight loops. To avoid dynamic allocations are runtime, I thought it might be nice to store these matrices in an `std::array`, and then pass iterators to this array as function arguments. As a trivial example, consider:

```
const int N = 3;
const int SIZE = 125;
typedef std::array<Eigen::Matrix<double, SIZE, 1>, N> MatrixArray;

void computeMatrixProductArray(MatrixArray::const_iterator BeginIn,
                               MatrixArray::const_iterator BeginEnd,
                               MatrixArray::iterator BeginOut,
                               MatrixArray::iterator EndOut) 
{

  Eigen::Matrix<double, SIZE, 1> Test;
  for (int J = 0; J < N; ++J) {
    *(BeginOut + J) = Test.array() * (*(BeginIn + J)).array();
  }

}

int main() 
{

  MatrixArray ArrayIn, ArrayOut;
  computeMatrixProductArray(ArrayIn.cbegin(), ArrayIn.cend(),
                            ArrayOut.begin(), ArrayOut.end());

}
```

My question has to do with the alignment of the matrices stored in `MatrixArray`, and how Eigen3.3 treats unaligned memory. The size of the matrices, and the properties of `std::array`, ensure that an individual matrix in a `MatrixArray` will certainly not be aligned on any nice boundary. However, to my understanding, Eigen3.3 can still vectorize this case with unaligned operations.

Can anyone provide insight on what happens in the above example when `J == 1`, and the first entry of this matrix is not aligned? Does Eigen3.3 now treat this case similarly to what happens with equivalent dynamic matrices? My understanding here is that scalar, or unaligned, operations are used until an appropriate alignment boundary is reached, at which time fully aligned operations will be used. Or, since the matrix is not aligned to begin with, there is no chance of aligned vectorization? Or is something else happening entirely?

Thanks for any insight, and thanks to the developers for maintaining such a powerful library.

Comment: Did you consider using `Eigen::Matrix<double, SIZE, N>` instead of `std::array<Eigen::Matrix<double, SIZE, 1>, N>`?

Comment: The generated assembly depends on several factors and the logic improve with Eigen versions, so to be sure, look at the generated assembly.

Comment: @chtz we had originally taken this approach, and performed operations on columns within each function. This was quite convenient, but we noticed it was significantly slower than operating on an `std::vector` of 1-D matrices. This was using dynamically sized matrices however, and it's possible that Eigen3.3 now makes this tenable. I'll give it a shot again with a small example. @ggael this is our usual approach. The packed instructions are in there, but they're also mixed up with quite a few scalar instructions so it gets a bit difficult to reason. Will keep digging. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @mike It might have been caused by the way you passed the matrices to your function. If the function expectes a `const VectorXd&` and you pass a column of a bigger matrix, there will be a temporary created.